# Global boolean does not keep value from another method - Java

Tags: java, paintcomponent, graphics2d

I want to go through an ArrayList of lines; for each line, I check whether it is outside a certain region. It works up to here. Then, if the line is outside the specified region, I want to add the line to another ArrayList (linesOutside) and then call repaint() to redraw those lines in another colour. This is the part which does not seem to work. The codes inside `if (Clip == true)` in `paintComponent()` are not executed at all (I tested using a message box). I have set Clip to True before calling repaint() in actionPerformed. Why is Clip not keeping this value when it enters paintComponent() then?

SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class testClipping extends JPanel implements MouseListener, ActionListener, MouseMotionListener
{
    //JComponents
    static JFrame frame;
    static JPanel drawingPanel;
    static JButton btnSetClip;
    static JButton btnClip;

    //used to draw lines
    double x1, y1, x2, y2;
    boolean FirstPoint;
    ArrayList<Line2D.Double> lines;
    ArrayList<Line2D.Double> linesOutside; 

    //used to draw rectangle for clipping
    Point startDrag, endDrag;
    Rectangle2D rectangle;
    boolean SetClip;

    //used to clip
    boolean Clip;
    double X1, Y1, X2, Y2;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                CreateFrame();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void CreateFrame()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Interface");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.add(new testClipping());
    }

    public testClipping()
    {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        CreateToolBar();
        CreateDrawingPanel();
        repaint(); //draw graph
        lines = new ArrayList<Line2D.Double>();
        btnSetClip.addActionListener(this);
        btnClip.addActionListener(this);
    }

    //create tool bar which contains commands to drawing functions
    private void CreateToolBar()
    {
        JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar(JToolBar.VERTICAL);
        btnSetClip = new JButton("Set clip area");
        btnClip = new JButton("Clip");
        toolbar.add(btnSetClip);
        toolbar.addSeparator();
        toolbar.add(btnClip);
        btnSetClip.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        btnClip.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        toolbar.setMargin(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
        toolbar.setFloatable(false);
        toolbar.setBackground(Color.black);
        add(toolbar, BorderLayout.WEST);
    }

    //create area where to draw
    private void CreateDrawingPanel()
    {
         drawingPanel = new JPanel()
         {
             public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
             {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                for (Line2D.Double line : lines) 
                {
                    g2.drawLine((int)line.getX1(), (int)line.getY1(), (int)line.getX2(), (int)line.getY2());
                }
                if (SetClip == true) //draw rectangle to specify clipping area
                {
                    if (startDrag != null && endDrag != null) 
                    {
                        rectangle = makeRectangle(startDrag.x, startDrag.y, endDrag.x, endDrag.y);
                        g2.draw(rectangle);
                    }
                }
                if (Clip == true) //redraw, in blue, lines outside clipping area
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "blue"); //FOR TESTING PURPOSE; DOES NOT EVEN EXECUTE; MEANING CLIP != TRUE
                    g2.setColor(Color.blue);
                    for (Line2D.Double lineOut : linesOutside) 
                    {
                        g2.drawLine((int)lineOut.getX1(), (int)lineOut.getY1(), (int)lineOut.getX2(), (int)lineOut.getY2());
                    }
                }
             }
         };
        add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        drawingPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
        drawingPanel.addMouseListener(this);
        drawingPanel.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        if (SetClip == true) //save starting points for rectangle
        {
            startDrag = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
            endDrag = startDrag;
            repaint();
        }
        if (FirstPoint == false) //save coordinates of first point
        {
            x1 = e.getX();
            y1 = e.getY();
            FirstPoint = true;
        }
        else //save coordinates of second point, add first and second points to array and draw line
        {
            x2 = e.getX();
            y2 = e.getY();
            Line2D.Double line = new Line2D.Double(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            lines.add(line);
            repaint();
            FirstPoint = false;
        }
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        endDrag = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        rectangle = makeRectangle(startDrag.x, startDrag.y, e.getX(), e.getY());
        repaint();
    }

    private Rectangle2D.Float makeRectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) 
    {
        return new Rectangle2D.Float(Math.min(x1, x2), Math.min(y1, y2), Math.abs(x1 - x2), Math.abs(y1 - y2));
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == btnSetClip) //user wants to set clip area
        {
            SetClip = true; //flag for paintComponent to know that rectangle has to be drawn
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == btnClip) //user wants to perform clipping
        {
            //find x and y values of boundary lines of clipping area
            double Xmin, Xmax, Ymin, Ymax;
            Xmin = rectangle.getMinX();
            Xmax = rectangle.getMaxX();
            //interchange Ymin and Ymax because of Java coordinate system
            Ymin = rectangle.getMaxY();
            Ymax = rectangle.getMinY();
            for (Line2D.Double line : lines) //for each line in drawing panel...
            {
                //determine if first point inside clipping area
                X1 = line.getX1();
                Y1 = line.getY1();
                //save bit codes
                String bit1 = ""; //first point
                String bit2 = ""; //second point
                bit1 = CalculateBit(Ymax - Y1); //first bit
                bit1 = bit1 + CalculateBit(Y1 - Ymin);//second bit
                bit1 = bit1 + CalculateBit(X1 - Xmax);//third bit
                bit1 = bit1 + CalculateBit(Xmin - X1);//fourth bit
                //determine if second point inside clipping area
                X2 = line.getX2();
                Y2 = line.getY2();
                bit2 = CalculateBit(Ymax - Y2); //first bit
                bit2 = bit2 + CalculateBit(Y2 - Ymin);//second bit
                bit2 = bit2 + CalculateBit(X2 - Xmax);//third bit
                bit2 = bit2 + CalculateBit(Xmin - X2);//fourth bit
                //perform logical AND on bit codes
                int b1 = Character.getNumericValue(bit1.charAt(0)) * Character.getNumericValue(bit2.charAt(0));
                int b2 = Character.getNumericValue(bit1.charAt(1)) * Character.getNumericValue(bit2.charAt(1));
                int b3 = Character.getNumericValue(bit1.charAt(2)) * Character.getNumericValue(bit2.charAt(2));
                int b4 = Character.getNumericValue(bit1.charAt(3)) * Character.getNumericValue(bit2.charAt(3));
                String LogicalAND;
                LogicalAND = Integer.toString(b1) + Integer.toString(b2) + Integer.toString(b3) + Integer.toString(b4);
                if ((bit1.equals("0000")) && (bit2.equals("0000"))) //both points within clip area
                {
                    //no clipping to perform
                }
                else if (!(LogicalAND.equals("0000")))
                {
                    Clip = true;
                    Line2D.Double lineOut = new Line2D.Double(X1, Y1, X2, Y2);
                    linesOutside.add(lineOut);
                }
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }

    //find whether bit is 0 or 1 to know position of point relative to clipping area
    public String CalculateBit (double a)
    {
        if (a > 0)
        {
            return "1";
        }
        else
        {
            return "0";
        }
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}

}
```

Comment: Is `Clip` ever set to true? - Also, why not use the methods for intersection provided in java.awt.geom classes?

Comment: Even if I place `Clip = true` just before repaint() in actionPerformed, it does not work.

Comment: You might also paint everything in the "outside colour", then use Graphics clipRect and paint "everything" again, in the "inside colour".

Comment: linesOutside is not empty?

Comment: @Phantom does it not show the messageDialog either if you put Clip = true; just in front of repaint? if not: it probably never gets into "else if (e.getSource() == btnClip)" statement for some reason?

Comment: Maybe try to use a debug tool ?

Comment: @Subler: No, it does not show the messageDialog and, no, it does get in `else if (e.getSource() == btnClip)` (I tested using a messageDialog there).

Comment: only thing i can think of then is that paintComponent is not actually getting called? but i dont see why it wouldnt... so im assuming it is, .. but then that means clip has to be true, if you put it in front of that repaint() statement, and you said it is getting called because you tested with another messagedialog... clip is never set to false anywhere... try printing out the value of Clip before your if(clip == true) ?

Comment: @Subler: I tried printing out the value of Clip before `if (Clip == true)` and it shows false.